# Checking for an array in a list, with "List<int[]>.Contains(new int[] { .. })", always returns false

Tags: c#, contains

I am trying to check if list that consists of int[2] arrays contains certain element.

In short, why this produces false?
And how can I check this properly?

```
List < int[] > ngonPairs = new List<int[]> {new int[2] { 0, 1 }};

bool flag = ngonPairs.Contains(new int[2] { 0, 1 });
```

Flag is always false.

Comment: It contains by reference equals. You have two different instances of int[]

Comment: Off topic: You don't must add the length of the array, if you create it like this: new int[]{0,1} ;) You can remove the 2 ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because

```
new[]{1, 2} != new[]{1, 2}
```

They are different arrays, and changes to one won't be reflected in the other.

However using LINQ's `SequenceEqual`, you can compare the ***contents*** of two sequences:

```
new[]{1, 2}.SequenceEqual(new[]{1, 2}) // == true
```

Now, using LINQ's `Any` you could:

```
bool flag = ngonPairs.Any(p => p.SequenceEqual(new int[] {0, 1}));
```

`.Any` operates over a sequence and returns `true` if any of the items in the sequence satisfy the predicate.

In this case, the predicate compares a single items from `ngonPairs` (i.e. arrays), and we can then use `SequenceEqual` described above to compare each of those arrays to our known array.

Comment: Translation: Set flag to true if Any member of ngonPairs is a list of elements that is exactly the same as the elements in this array of integers I just newed up.

Comment: Would this search is faster with arrays rather than lists? Instead of List<int[]> I would use int[][]? Or not so much faster?

Comment: Arrays are always faster than Lists, since Lists are just a wrapper around arrays.

Comment: @PetrasVestartas Do what is most obvious. If it's slow, and that's important, measure that later. Don't try to guess where your program will be slow. Try to make it ***correct***.

Comment: The official reading for `=>` is: "goes to". `p` is stand for an item in the `ngonPairs` list. `p.SequenceEqual(new int[2] { 0, 1 })` is a predicate based on this `p`. Instead of `p` you can use any valid identifier.

Comment: @spender - of course, given two equally simple and readable solutions, always choose the optimal one.

Comment: Lists can grow, arrays not. If you know the size in adavance and the size  is fixed, you can use an array. Otherwise use a `List<T>`.

Comment: @hoodaticus May I ask how to use the same approach but for flipped pairs? I want to check pairs  bool flag = ngonPairs.Any(p => p.SequenceEqual(new int[] {0, 1}));  and bool flag = ngonPairs.Any(p => p.SequenceEqual(new int[] {1, 0})); Is it possible to do this in one line?

Comment: @PetrasVestartas - you should be able to reverse the sequence using .Reverse(), and instead of doing two lines just OR the first p.SequenceEqual with the second one inside a single Any call.

Answer (score 1):

List contains an array object, but you are trying to search for another newly created object. Both array objects are different, so it always return false. If your intention is to compare the values of the array, you can use EqualityComparer to check.

Write a comparer to compare two arrays. Following code snippet is the example and it will just compare int array of size two.

```
class ArrayComparer : EqualityComparer<int[]>
    {
        public override bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
        {

            if (x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1])
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then use this EqualityComparer instance in the Contains function to compare the array values;

```
bool flag = ngonPairs.Contains(new int[2] { 0, 1 }, new ArrayComparer());
```

Comment: Theoretically correct, although I'd hate to be duped by this API when I have arrays larger than 2 items.

Comment: This is just sample, this can be enhanced to handle arrays larger than size 2 and validations needed if the given two array objects are in different size.

Comment: `public override bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y) { return Enumerable.SequenceEquals(x, y); }` =^_^=