# check if List<int[]> contains a given int[]

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I check if an `ArrayList<int[]>` contains a given array [x, y]? I have found [the same question in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789252/checking-for-an-array-in-a-list-with-listint-containsnew-int), but can't find any answers for java.

At the moment I am using `myList.contains(myArray)` but it is always evaluating to false, I assume for similar reasons as in C#. The solution in C# is to use LINQ, which does not exist in java.

Is there another way I can do this or will I have to write my own subroutine to pull out the values of each list element and compare them manually?

---

Edit: I've written my own subroutine to do this which works (assuming each array has two elements), but a more elegant solution would be appreciated

```
private boolean contains(List<int[]> list, int[] array) {
    for (int[] listItem : list) {
        if (listItem[0] == array[0] &&
           listItem[1] == array[1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: A remark: du to the fact that generics are invariant and erased, and arrays are covariant and retained, mixing them sets you up for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The `.contains` method compares each object with `.equals` which as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777279/220627) answer points out just compares the identity of the array objects (i.e. checks if they're the same Java object), it does not compare the contents of the arrays.

What you need to do is to write a for loop, check each element with `Arrays.equals(..)` (which compares the contents of the arrays). For example:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
    if (Arrays.equals(myArray, myList.get(i)) found = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[])), and also [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)s, which are designed for similar use cases as LINQ. In this case, the [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method is very similar to `Any` in LINQ.

Combining these two, you can write your method in one statement:

```
private boolean contains(List<int[]> list, int[] array) {
    return list.stream()
        .anyMatch(x -> Arrays.equals(x, array));
}
```